# Designating Jersey resource handler based on Accept header value

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, dropwizard

I'd like to have different functions handling requests for a particular resource based on the Accept header. Specifically if the Accept header is present, a function returning content-type of application/json should be invoked, otherwise if no Accept header is present a different function returning text/plain content should be invoked. Is there a way to do this with Jersey annotations?

This is in the context of a dropwizard json web service by the way.

Comment: Do you use the `@Produces` annotation in any of your methods?

Comment: Yep I do use @Produces. I can set up multiple values for Produces but I'm not returning a Resource instance so I can't set content type on the response. I was hoping to be able to be able to determine which function handles requests with a certain Accept header so that each function would produce one content type.

Comment: According to this tutorial (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/gipxf/index.html) the `Accept` header is used to determine what method (annotated with `@Produces`) will be called. Different methods will produce different content types. Isn't that what you need? Can you post your code to make your question more clear?

Comment: I'm using this backend in conjunction with blueimps jquery file uploader which will either include an Accept header of application/json or not include one at all. If no Accept header is specified I'd like the response content type to be text/plain.

Comment: What's the signature (with annotations) of the method in question?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (which is why I came here). The hint about `@Produces` solved the problem:

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/Test")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public class TestResource {
   @GET
   @Path("/test")
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   public String json() {
      return "{\"hello\": \"world\"}";
   }

   @GET
   @Path("/test")
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
   public String xml() {
      return "<hello>World</hello>";
   }

   @GET
   @Path("/test")
   public String html() {
      return "<html>Hello world</html>";
   }
}
```

Calling the "/Test/test" service now gives different results depending on the "Accept" header.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, its been a while and I don't remember how I solved my original issue but hopefully this helps others.